# C++ shared_ptr and built-in pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

Delete twice built-in pointers cause undefined, but what happened in this situation?
In this code, is shared pointer undefined?

```
string *str_1 = new string;
std::shared_ptr<string> str_ptr(str_1);

*str_1 = "C++";
cout << *str_ptr << endl;
*str_ptr = "C#";
cout << *str_1 << endl;

// str_1 & str_ptr refers same piece of memory    
delete str_1;

cout << *str_ptr << endl;  // Is this undefined?
```

Comment: Obviously it's undefined behavior

Comment: Yes, it obviously is UB. Do not use a pointer (even for comparison), after deleting it.

Comment: You use `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` etc. to manage object lifetime for you automatically. Don't try to manage it manually after handing it over. It's better style to construct the smart pointer directly from the `new` expression, and never have an un-managed raw pointer at all.

Comment: @Useless and is even better to use a `make_shared()` call ;). There is no `std::make_unique()` tough, at least in C++11

Comment: On Linux at least, compile with at least `g++ -Wall -g` and use `gdb` (the debugger) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find memory leaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is undefined because after the call to deletion of the raw pointer, the `shared_ptr` is left with a dangling pointer reference. You then proceed to dereference the already freed memory (undefined behavior 1). When the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope, it will call `delete` on the pointer it was told to manage, which is freeing already freed memory (undefined behavior 2).

As a convenience, `shared_ptr` allows initialization from a raw pointer, but you are supposed to allow it to manage the allocated memory afterwards. It is an error to manage the raw pointer (eg, delete it or initialize another `shared_ptr`) when you have given it to `shared_ptr`.

It is actually better practice, when using `shared_ptr` to use the helper function `make_shared`.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> sp = std::make_shared<std::string>("C++");
```

This format avoids you having to deal with creating a raw pointer. It also turns out to be more efficient because it avoids an extra allocation the smart pointer would have to do if it was passed a raw pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`sharped_ptr` is no magic. It simply calls `delete` once the last `shared_ptr` to an object is destroyed. Thus, your code calls `delete` twice, once when you delete `str_1` and then when `str_ptr` goes out of scope. Thus, using a `shared_ptr` doesn't change anything in comparision to calling `delete` twice explicitly: The result is undefined behaviour.

`shared_ptr` was invented to take the burden of explicit `delete` calls from you. Thus, there is also simply no reason for using `shared_ptr` *and* explicit `delete` together. So even if it did not result in undefined behaviour, my advice would still be: *Don't do it!*